# Firebase: how to update data only if missing or different? (eg User registration)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is a pretty basic question and I'm surprised that the Firebase guides don't cover it. In their own example of registering a user, the code seems very inefficient unless there is some built-in optimization I'm unaware of. It seems each time you log in, you will also push the user data to firebase.

```
ref.authWithPassword("jenny@example.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple",
    new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        // Authentication just completed successfully :)
        // irrelevant: some code to construct userData
        ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(userData);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {
        // Something went wrong :(
    }
});
```

1) There appear to be no checks if a user already exists at that location and if the data we are attempting to persist is different. How would one accomplish that? Would you need to first read the fields, check if different and then attempt to update (all of this in a transaction)?

2) If I'm right about (1), would you recommend storing some indicative data locally to short-circuit the need to "check" with firebase if the user is registered? I could store a boolean + a local copy of the user so I can (A) check the registered boolean and if true, then (B) check if the local user data is the same. If both are true, I can completely skip step (1) above.

Obviously I want to avoid any caching logic in app space due to the usual complexity cost. Does Firebase guarantee super fast local-only queries (what I'd do in (1)) if the data hasn't been changed? I want to avoid extra client logic as much as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may overestimate how often `authWithPassword()` runs. In a well-implemented Firebase app, you will use an `onAuth()` listener to detect when a user has previously signed in. So you'll only need to actively authenticate them when their session has expired or otherwise has become invalid.

If you'd prefer to only write the user's profile data when they first sign-up, you can do the same logic when you call `ref.createUser()`.

To know client-side whether the data is the same, you'd indeed first have to read it. Which negates any positive effect you might gain by not writing it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the .createUser API, I'll look into it. So looks like I'll need to keep local indicators. It doesn't matter if I just do it once every 24 hours, etc. I don't want to push the user data unnecessarily. To your last point, technically, Firebase would know the "latest" (in some random ordering of events) state of the data locally and could do a local comparison and ignore the update if the results match. So I don't really need to do a full blown 'pull' read each time to compare given FB's nature.